# Continuity of equivalence relations

Tags: gn.general-topology, terminology

A function $\varphi : X \rightarrow Y$ between two topological spaces is continuous if and only if $\varphi(\,\overline{A}\,) \subset  \overline{\varphi(A)}$ for all $A \subset X$.

This property can be extended to equivalence relations as follows.
Given an equivalence relation $R$ on $X$ and $A \subset X$, we denote by $R(A)$ the set of points equivalent to points in A. We can look at the property of $R$ given by

$$R\Bigl(\overline{A}\Bigr) \subset \overline{R(A)} \ \ for\  \ all\ \ A ⊂ X.$$

Is there a name for that property? Is it studied somewhere? Can it be formulated in term of the continuity of some function associated To $R$?

I encountered this property while studying the equivalence relation associated to a foliation ("being on the same leaf").

Comment: It seems that this condition is equivalent to: the closure of an $R$-saturated set is $R$-saturated.

Comment: This property is related to the rotundness (of quasi-uniformities) considered in http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.topol.2015.12.010

Comment: Rotund quasi-uniformities also are normal quasi-uniformities, see   http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.1504

Comment: So, one can call equivalence relations $R$ satisfying $R(\bar A)\subset \overline{R(A)}$ for all $A\subset X$ $rotund$ or $normal$.

Comment: Does adh denote closure?

Comment: I think "adh" is short for "adherence", which I believe is indeed the same as closure but mostly used in French.